# Spark captured variable is null if the code is pasted via :paste

Tags: apache-spark

If I execute this piece of code

```scala
  val foo = "foo"

  def f(arg: Any): Unit = {
    Option(42).foreach(_ => java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(foo, "foo"))
  }

  sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2), 2).foreach(f)
```

in `spark2-shell` via `:paste` it throws

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  val foo = "foo"

  def f(arg: Any): Unit = {
    Option(42).foreach(_ => java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(foo, "foo"))
  }

  sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2), 2).foreach(f)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

19/03/11 15:02:06 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, hadoop.company.com, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException: foo
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
```

However if I execute it pasting without `:paste` or via `spark2-shell -i` it doesn't.

Furthermore if I touch `foo` inside `f` the code starts to work even when pasted via `:paste`

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val foo = "foo"

  def f(arg: Any): Unit = {
    println(foo)
    Option(42).foreach(_ => java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(foo, "foo"))
  }

  sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2), 2).foreach(f)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

foo: String = foo
f: (arg: Any)Unit

scala>
```

What's going on?

Spark version 2.3.0.cloudera3

Comment: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27137